# Ionic 3 app - allow navigation to page if user logged (check on one place, rather on every component)

Tags: authentication, ionic3, angular5

How can I add check whether user is logged or not and in accordance with that, allow navigation to desired page or not? It wouldn't be good practice to add :

```js
ionViewCanEnter() {
  return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
}
```

check at the top of every component...

Comment: How have you implemented your authentication? Are you using Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an authentication token for your user login. This will allow you to locally store as a variable or local storage and you can implement in your service or provider to be used throughout the app. If you're uncertain with how they work there are plenty of resources online, but ultimately it comes down to your back-end server. Here's an example:[Auth Token Example](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-json-web-tokens-jwt-for-custom-authentication-in-ionic-2-part-2/)

Also, I would recommend you use `*ngIf` statement blocks in your html pages where the buttons navigate to the pages themselves and throw an alert if the user tries clicking on the button to navigate.

I have some sample code that can help guide you with this as well.

LoginPage.ts

```js
          
            // API POST authentication
            this.API.validateUser(form.value).then((result) =>{
              form.reset();//clears values of the form after data is saved to array
              this.res = JSON.parse(result.toString());//converts result to array
              //console.log(this.res);
              if(this.res.token!=""){//sets authtoken to local storage
              this.storage.set('authToken',this.res.token)
                  }
              //console.log(localStorage);
              if(this.res.status == true){
               setTimeout(() => {
                LoginPage.initialLogin = true;
                this.navCtrl.push(MenuPage);
                 loading.dismiss();
              }, 1000);
            }
```

MenuPage.ts

```js
// MenuPage.ts 
 /* calls local storage once user hits menupage*/

     if(LoginPage.initialLogin==true){
        //console.log('Initial Login is:',LoginPage.initialLogin);
       this.storage.get('authToken').then((data)=>{//grabs local storage auth token
       if(data!=null){
       //console.log('GET request happened');
       this.loggedIn = true;//User is logged in
       this.reap.grabAPIData(data);//calls service to grab API data on initial login
        }
     });
    }
    else{
      this.reap.getLocalStorage();
      //console.log('Initial Login is:',LoginPage.initialLogin);
    }
```

MenuPage.html

This is where you can use your value to determine what the user can see or not see. The button can be hidden or you can throw an alert in the .ts file that lets user know they aren't logged in.

```html
  <ion-item   *ngIf="loggedIn" no-lines>
    <button  class="menuButton" ion-button large block (tap)="toNexPage()" >
     Next page</button>
  </ion-item>
```